# Three.js - ArrowHelper not showing up

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been stuck trying to draw an arrow using `THREE.ArrowHelper` for multiple hours now, hopefully, someone can shine some light on the issue. My code is as follows:

```
function draw_an_arrow(name, from, to, color, layer) {
    let direction = to.clone().sub(from)
    let length = direction.length()
    let obj = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, color)
    obj.name = name
    obj.layers.set(layer)  
    scene.add(obj)
    return obj
}
```

The `name`, `from`, `to`, `color`, and `layer` are provided function parameters in the correct format. This is verified. The provided `layer` and `scene` also work. When drawing anything else within the same function such as a plane, circle, or even line they show up. Since my visualization is 2D, all objects are drawn with z-coordinate 0 and my camera hovers orthogonally over x-y-plane.

The code I am using follows most of the examples I found online to the letter. What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:** When I `console.log(obj)` at the end of the function, I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you use `from`, as a variable? Can you rename `from` into anything else and try again?  You might also want to check the size of the arrow. Try something large to see if it shows up: `let obj = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, 100, color)`. Or maybe the camera's position is off, so play with that too: `camera.position.set(0, 0, 100)` and `camera.lookAt(scene.position)`. Also, try removing the layer, I never used one so I don't know if that'll change things. Finally, try the ArrowHelper position: `obj.position.set(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Tried everything you mentioned, unfortunatly didn't change anything. Parameters are verified to be the correct type/values. I use layers to be able to toggle visibility of certain objects. When I draw something else on the same layer, it works. Also when I console print the created arrows and inspect, all the parameters seem to be right. I added the log to my main post.

Comment: I found the issue, it were the layers after all. Seems the `layers.set()` does not work on an `ArrowHelper`?

Comment: Good to know! As I said, I never used layers anyway so I would try to remove the layers and see if it works. Cool